# Windows Server User denied write access when explicitly given rights

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, windows-10

I just took over administration of a network which has a lot of problems. It's a Windows network, and the DC is running 2008 R2. There are mostly Windows 7 machines with some Windows 10 boxes here and there (most were upgraded in place, some were restored after the upgrade).

Currently, I have a user who needs r/w access to three folders on a network share. They are a member of four groups (let's call them group 1-4). Group 1 has access to Folder 1, Group 2 has access to Folder 2, and the user has explicit access to Folder 3 (they're the only employee who accesses that folder). Groups 3&4 have access to two other folders, but this user doesn't seem to use them much (for the record though, the user also has issues with those folders).

The problems started last week, one day before I arrived. Everything was apparently working before a Windows 10 update rolled around (things were working fine on this computer while running Windows 10 prior to Wednesday last week, and it was an upgrade from Win7). After the update, the user only had read access to all files in those three folders. I ended up creating a new account on the server, and copied their documents to a new folder on the server owned by their new account. There are no roaming profiles that I know of, but a user share is mounted as the Z:\ drive locally on the machine for document storage. It became apparent that the Win10 update had failed somehow and broke the machine severely, so it was replaced with a spare.

After re-adding group membership and logging in to the profile on the new computer (a fresh install of Windows 10), they were able to access Folder 1 again. Access to folders 2 and 3 remain intermittent. Read access is fine, but write access is denied most of the time (closing the user's session under Share and Storage management, and then restarting the workstation fixes the permissions issue temporarily, but it either fails after a period of time, or after a restart, and it doesn't work 100% of the time). Making the user the owner of Folder 3 fixed write access for that folder after a restart, but then failed again after a second restart.

Creating new folders, reassigning permissions for groups to the folders, and then copying the data to the new folders also temporarily fixed the issue, but once more things broke after one or two restarts (this was also inconsistent).

There were some ACL entries farther up in the directory tree where the old user account was explicitly given read access, but they were superfluous and I removed them (seemed like an attempt at a quick fix by the old IT admin). This didn't seem to change anything.

It should be noted that other users can access these folders without any problems.

In addition, this user (jesmith), is the only user who's "Open File" entries in Share Management shows two slashes in the file URL.
[image: DoubleSlash]

I'm working on getting approval for a new server (this one isn't even a server, it's using desktop hardware which is 6 years old by now at least) so that I can just rebuild the domain from the ground up, but that might take a while. So I'm stuck fixing this in the mean time.

Comment: I'd be hard pressed to see this as a permissions issue. Permissions don't sometimes work and sometimes not. Have you tried with this user from a different computer?

Comment: Yes, we tried it on a computer that was already a part of the domain and was not having issues (running Windows 7), as well as a new computer we had as a spare (running Windows 10, like the first computer). Same issue in both cases.